# Gensim LDA giving output of Topic IDs but probabilities are not adding up to 1

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, gensim, topic-modeling, unsupervised-learning

I have trained the LDA model to cluster 100 topic, and according to my knowledge, every topic should be outputted with a certain probabiliy, all adding up to 1.

But when I run this code, I am getting only 2 topics.

Please help.

```
text = "A blood cell, also called a hematocyte, is a cell produced by hematopoiesis and normally found in blood."

# transform text into the bag-of-words space
bow_vector = dictionary.doc2bow(tokenize(text))
lda_vector = lda_model[bow_vector]
print("LDA Output: ", lda_vector)
print("\nTop Keywords from highest prob Topic: ",lda_model.print_topic(max(lda_vector, key=lambda item: item[1])[0]))
print("\n\nAddition of all the probabilities from LDA output:",functools.reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,[i[1] for i in lda_vector]))
```

> LDA Output:  [(64, 0.6952628), (69, 0.18223721)]
>
> Top Keywords from highest prob Topic:  0.042*"health" + 0.032*"medical" + 0.017*"patients" + 0.016*"cancer" + 0.015*"hospital" + 0.015*"said" + 0.015*"treatment" + 0.012*"doctors" + 0.012*"care" + 0.012*"drug"
>
> Addition of all the probabilities from LDA output: 0.8775

Answer (score 0):

If you set the parameter `minimum_probability` of `LdaModel` to `0`, the sum will be `1` (or near `1` due to approximation errors). It controls filtering the topics returned for a document.